# Angular 10 reactive form - update array of checkboxes AFTER the form has displayed

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular (10) reactive form that includes a list of checkboxes

The data in the form can be updated after the form is displayed, and I can't find a way of using 'setValue' to update the checkboxes.  If I push in boolean values using 'setValue' I'm getting "expecting string" errors.

Any suggestions?

Part of the form is shown below...

```
 <div id="states" class="in-column" formGroupName="states">
            <h3 class="card-body-title">States</h3>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px">
              <smart-button class="flat">All</smart-button>
              <smart-button class="flat">None</smart-button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateOpen">Open</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateWIP">WIP</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="statePending">Pending review</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateOnhold">On hold</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateSuspended">Suspended</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateWaiting">Waiting for</smart-check-box>
            </div>
            <div>
              <smart-check-box formControlName="stateDelegated">Delegated</smart-check-box>
            </div>
```

Part of the method that pushes data into the form is shown below...
(the 'hasState'method returns a 'boolean' value)

```
    this.filterForm.get('states').setValue({
      stateOpen: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.open),
      stateWIP: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.wip),
      statePending: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.pendingReview),
      stateOnhold: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.onHold),
      stateSuspended: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.suspended),
      stateWaiting: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.waitingFor),
      stateDelegated: data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.delegated)
    });
```

Comment: Please set up an example on [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) and show us what you've attempted so far.

Comment: What do you mean Angular (1)?

Comment: Using the 'setValue' code shown above I get an error....   smart.card.js:8 Invalid 'value' property value type! Actual type: 'boolean', Expected type: 'string'!

Comment: Please show us the `SmartCheckBox` component

Answer (score 0):

Try making the property name a string. Eg:

```
 this.filterForm.get('states').setValue({
      'stateOpen': data.stateFilter.hasState(GdTaskWorkflowState.open),...}
```

Alternatively, try wrapping formControlName in [].

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - the '<smart-checkbox'>' is not compatible with reactive forms.  Change this tag for a standard   checkbox and everything works fine.